# Project Euler #179

Tags: c

Problem: Find the number of integers 1 < n < 10^7, for which n and n + 1 have the same number of positive divisors. For example, 14 has the positive divisors 1, 2, 7, 14 while 15 has 1, 3, 5, 15.

I can't reach 10^7 because it is too big number for C and me. How can i solve this problem in C?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int divisorcount(int);

int main()
{
    int number,divisornumber1,divisornumber2,j=0;

    for(number=1;number<=100;number++){
        divisornumber1=divisorcount(number);
        divisornumber2=divisorcount(number-1);
        if(divisornumber1==divisornumber2){
            printf("%d and %d\n",number-1,number);
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThere is %d integers.",j);

    getch();
}

int divisorcount(int num)
{
    int i,divi=0;
    for(i=1;i<=(num)/2;i++)
        if(num%i==0)
            divi++;
    return divi;
}
```

Comment: Too big for `int`, not C. Use a `long long` instead.

Comment: Instead of finding the number that can divide, you can work backward and mark all multiple of a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever tried `long long num = 100000000LL;`? C isn't smart enough to conclude the type on the right side from the left `long long` so you have to add the `LL`. With this approach you should be able to handle larger numbers than normal integers, just change your functions and variables in a suitable way.

A `long long` is always at least `2^64` bit in size which you can check on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types).

*Hint:* As someone mentioned in the comments, Project Euler is not about bruteforcing. This is a lame approach. Think about some better strategies. You might want to get help at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

**EDIT:** I don't know why I thought, that a `uint32_t` is not enough for `10^7` - sorry for that mistake.

Comment: 10^7 should fit in `int` for 32-bit computer, unless the OP is using 16-bit compiler...

Comment: You're right... why did I think this is the issues?! o.O I will leave this answer due to its general content about data types.

Comment: Is `long long` defined by C89?

Comment: @pmg: `long long` is defined by C99 but **NOT** C89.

Comment: This problem can be solved with brute force, just a clever way of brute forcing so that it runs fast.

Comment: ok i got it, your solution is working. but it takes a long time, is there any way to shorten the program?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: ok thanks. I wonder if the OP is using Turbo C ... his use of <conio.h> probably indicates so.

Comment: @doruk: As i mentioned in my answer, you need a good strategy in general how to bruteforce in an intelligent manner (e.g. ignore primes maybe?) or how to use different properties from number theory. This would be suitable for math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

As a hint to how to solve the problem within a minute, you can go through each number from 2 to 10^7, loop through all multiples of the those numbers and increment by 1 (1 is ignored, since all numbers are multiple of 1). In the end, you will get the number of divisors of each of the numbers in the array (check whether your compiler support 32-bit index). Just use a final linear scan to count.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on nhahtdh's idea, to make it even faster (at cost of making it more complicated), make a prime number sieve calculating the prime numbers up to sqrt(10^7) = about 3170. Then the exponents of prime factors determine the number of multiples so that the product of (exp+1) is the number of integers dividing the number. So you can set an array to ones, then loop over each prime, multiplying with that primes exponent contribution (plus one) for each position it multiplies.